# Refresh text file contents to div in angular

Tags: html, angular, refresh

I have a text file on the server which contents I would like to display in a div using angular updating on every second. How could I do that?

```
<div>Update text file here every second</div>
```

This is my code, something like this? Doesn't seem to work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

private http: HttpClient;

 let myText: string;

  setInterval(() => { 
      getText();
  }
  ,1000);

  getText() {
    this.http.get("https://my.text.file/textFile.txt", { responseType: "text" }).subscribe(data => {
          this.myText = data;
    });
  }
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =
 this.myText(); 
 
 </script>

<div id="text"></div>


<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work and it is normal. You can't just paste code that I give you and hope it works. Before create an Angular application, you need to know Angular principles and concepts, you should read the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) before writing any piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval()` allows to call a function at specified intervals.

```
  let myText: string;

  setInterval(() => { 
      getText();
  }
  ,1000);

  getText() {
     this.http.get("http://api.example.com/text_file", { responseType: "text" }).subscribe(data => {
          this.myText = data;
    });
  }
```

Inject the HttpClient into your component by adding `private http: HttpClient` in the constructor (it can be public or private).
Then add a new method, that we can call `getText()`.
In that method, we call the HttpClient's `post` method.
Two important things at that point to note: the first parameter is the URL where the text file is stored or to access to it.
The second parameter is an object to set some options: here, we say to the HttpClient that the server will serve text instead of JSON (`responseType: 'text')`.
Because HttpClient's `get()`, `post()`, `delete()` and `put()` methods return an Observable, we have to subscribe to it: so, to that `subscribe()` method, we pass a function (`data => {}`) to get our data.
That data have to be stored somewhere, so, earlier, we created a variable called `myText` that is a string variable.
We use that variable to store our data that can be shown in the component's view.

Angular team provided a [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) to learn Angular principles, a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, and how do i get text? Hard to find info anywhere

Comment: Can't seem to find answer or i just dont get it